# Default caching behavior of IE 8 in absence of caching headers on SSL

Tags: http, internet-explorer, caching, ssl

What is the default caching behavior of IE 8 in absence of caching headers? If no headers have been set from the server side, how would it cache the response, or will it follow no-cache by default? The connection is secured i.e. HTTPS.

I am facing this problem where I write byte stream in response and the headers which I set are -

response.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=utf-8;");

response.setHeader("Content-Length", server.getContentLength() + "");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

I know this fact that if a user tries to download a file over a HTTPS connection, any response headers that prevent caching will cause the file download process to fail in Internet Explorer, but in my case no headers for caching have been specified explicitly. Then also IE 8 says -

Unable to download.

Internet Explorer was unable to open this site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

I am not getting the exact reason behind it. So, I can only make guesses about the default caching mechanism of IE 8. However it works fine in IE 9+ and in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact reason for this. It was set by our own code, which does for every response for a particular request. So, now I know that these headers are set by us, and in the code which provides the export functionality, I just overrode them to work properly for IE 8 -

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", ""); // HTTP 1.1

response.setHeader("Pragma", ""); // HTTP 1.0